# I'm making a triangle class finder and I'm stuck

Tags: python, geometry

I am coding a program that lets you type in the three angles or sides of a triangle, and it tells if it's equilateral, isosceles etc.  I am not worrying about the rest for now, but I'm stuck on the equilateral part of it.  Here is my code:

```
def idtri():
    print("\nDo you have all three sides, or al three angles?")
    print("(1) Sides")
    print("(2) Angles")
    choice = input()
    if choice == 1:
        print("\nType in the lengths of all of the sides.")
        t1 = input("1: ")
        t2 = input("2: ")
        t3 = input("3: ")
        print("Your triangle is an equalateral triangle.")
        menu()
    elif choice == 2:
        pass

 idtri()
```

Comment: I would think of how you define each of those triangles. If you have all three sides, all three being equal means equilateral, two isosceles, etc. You have used `==` and `if` already, so how could you write a function that incorporates those to return the type of triangle?

Comment: Well, I'm a little new to python, so I can't really think of any.  I tried to do if t1, t2, t3 == t2, t3, t1: then do all the rest, but that didn't work.

Comment: You are very close :) So focusing on equilateral, you are testing if they are equal to each other. If you compare two elements, it is `t1 == t2`. Following that logic, what is one way you could check for three elements being equal?

Comment: Closer. Looking at just the right side, how would check if `t2` and `t3` were equal?

Comment: I think if t2 == t3 is how you check the right side.

Comment: Exactly - so what if you said `t1 == t2 == t3`?

Comment: OH! Now I see why you said I was so close.  Thanks, I never know you could do that.

Comment: It's a nice little trick. That will get you the equilateral part - the other part is isosceles. There you only need to verify that any two sides are the same. Now how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that, for identifying the triangle as scalene, isoceles, or equilateral, it doesn't matter whether the three values you have are the angles or the side lengths, the process is:

> If all three values are the same, the triangle is equilateral;
>   otherwise, if any two values are the same, the triangle is isoceles;
>   otherwise, the triangle is scalene.

So you can write a simple function to return the type based on the number of equal values provided:

```
id_triangle = lambda a, b, c: {0: 'scalene', 1: 'isoceles', 3: 'equilateral'}\
                              [(a == b) + (a == c) + (b == c)]
```

and then call that from your interactive script, like:

```
print('Your triangle is %s.' % id_triangle(t1, t2, t3))
```

Comment: I just started python about a week ago, so what does lambda, and then the [(a == b) + (a == c) + (b == c)] part mean?

Comment: A lambda in Python is (roughly) just a way to define a simple one-liner function without necessarily giving it a name. In this case you could equivalently do `def id_triangle(a, b, c):` and then `return` the part after the colon. The `(a == b) + (a == c) + (b == c)` is adding up the boolean values of each pairwise comparison of the values (i.e. the number of equal sides/angles), which will be either 0, 1, or 3, and the `[]` use that result to index one of the strings in the dict (i.e. the appropriate triangle type name).

Comment: -1 for subscripting a dict with a sum of three bools. That's just horrible (especially when it's on the next line). If I didn't already know what this code does, I could stare at it for 20 minutes. Use an if/elif/else block instead.

Comment: I see the sum of bools as "the number of side-length equalities" and the dict as "the relation between number of side-length equalities and triangle nomenclature"; it's not an attempt at cleverness or obfuscation. If you prefer a procedural approach, might I suggest submitting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the counter from the Python collections:

```
from collections import Counter

def idtri():
    cnt = Counter()
    side1 = input('Enter length of first side: ')
    cnt[side1] += 1
    side2 = input('Enter length of second side: ')
    cnt[side2] += 1
    side3 = input('Enter length of third side: ')
    cnt[side3] += 1

    if 3 in cnt.values():
        print('Equilateral Triangle')
    elif 2 in cnt.values():
        print('Isosceles Triangle')
    else:
        print('Scalene Triangle')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    idtri()
```